# how to type in python selenium using execute_script

Tags: java, selenium

i am using selenium in python and wondering how can i type into the field through execute_script

i tried

```
driver.execute_script('driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("text")')
# the errors here say Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

and i also tried

```
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].sendKeys("text"), a)
# the error says arguments[0].sendKeys is not a function
```

all of my codes have implicit wait so it shouldn't be a problem with the element not loaded

P.s. i also see some forum but they use another way to locate element but i need to use xpath to locate those elements, is there a way to do so?

Comment: `driver.execute_script('driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("text")')` Here `execute_script()` is suppose to have the javascript as argument and I sense it is Java

Comment: Why are you mixing Java with Python?

Comment: In here `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].sendKeys("text"), a)`, `sendKeys()` is again the Java function and not javascript so does the error. If you able to get the element using driver.findElement(By.xpath('xpath')) then simply chain it like `driver.findElement(By.xpath('xpath')).sendKeys("xyz")`